# Ignore Category in Target Rules

Tags: category, targetrule

My client's website has many levels of category, and each level has it's own *All* category. They want to build target rules that include the "Product category **is** **the Same as Matched Product Cagegories**" however the *All* categories are messing that up. Here is an example:

```
A
    B
        C
            ✓
        D
            ✗
        E
            ✗
        B-All
            ✓
    F
        G
            ✗
        H
            ✓
        I
            ✗
        F-All
            ✓
    B-All
        ✓
A-All
    ✓
```

So the product belongs to `C`, `B-All`, `H`, `F-All` and `A-All`

If we setup the target rules like the following, we run into problems:

- Product category **is** **the Same as Matched Product Cagegories**
- Product Category **does not contain** **Constant Value** [the ids of the *all* categories]

The problem is that everything in `C` is also in `B-All`, so if we exclude `B-All` then all products in `C`, `D` and `E` get excluded.

We are looking for a way to say "ignore these categories when checking matched product categories". Is there any way to do that which is built in? Any suggestions on a simple code approach that will work?